# Grouping rows by multiply fields and return other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to group rows by multiply fields and return the other fields, like in my example, but it doesn't work.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {'$group': {'_id': {
            '$basic.last_name',
            '$basic.first_name'
        }, 'data': {'$last': '$$ROOT'}}},
        {'$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': '$data'}}
    ])
```

This variant works as excepted, the only thing I need to group by two fields:

```
db.collectio.aggregate([
        {'$group': {'_id': {'$basic.last_name', 'data': {'$last': '$$ROOT'}}},
        {'$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': '$data'}}
    ])
```

How can I reach my goal? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost close, the code has wrong syntax:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {'$group': {'_id': {
        'last_name': '$basic.last_name',
        'first_name': '$basic.first_name'
    }, 'data': {'$last': '$$ROOT'}}},
    {'$replaceRoot': {'newRoot': '$data'}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that I'm very close, but didn't think so :)